# I am getting array index in query string when use remote in jquery.How can I get its value in laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have send a get request

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
            termName:{
                required: true,
                maxlength:50,
                unique:true,
                /*termValidate : true,*/
                remote: {
                    url: "/term/unique",
                    type: "get",
                    data: {                        
                        memberId: function () {
                            return $("input[name='member_id']").val();
                        },
                    },
                    dataFilter: function (data) {
                        var json = JSON.parse(data);
                        if (json.id!=0) {
                            return "\"" + "{{Lang::get('messages.membership_name_already_taken')}}" + "\"";
                        } else {
                            return 'true';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

in controller

```
public function checkLimit()
    {

        $membership = Tenure::all()->where('name', Input::get('termName'))->first();
        if (Input::get('memberId')!=" ") {
            $id = Input::get('memberId');
        } else {
            $id = 0;
        }
        if($membership == null && $id == 0){
            $membership = ['id' => '0'];
        } else {
            if ($membership->id == $id) {
                $membership = ['id' => '0'];
            }
        }

        return Response::json($membership);
    }
```

i have used Input::get('termName') to get termName.but when i checked my querystring its like

http://localhost:8088/term/unique?term_name[0]=vfvfvfvffvff&memberId=

how can i get termname in controller?

Comment: Is your question about jQuery Validate or about a Laravel controller?   Please tag the question correctly so the best people can answer for you.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method

```
 public function checkLimit(Request $request)
        {

            $membership = Tenure::all()->where('name', $request->term_name->first());
            if ($request->memberId!="") {
                $id = $request->memberId;
            } else {
                $id = 0;
            }
            if($membership == null && $id == 0){
                $membership = ['id' => '0'];
            } else {
                if ($membership->id == $id) {
                    $membership = ['id' => '0'];
                }
            }

            return Response::json($membership);
        }
```